# Reading and Writing some parts of a line in another text file in a preferred format in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I do appreciate any detailed helps. I really am in a terrible situation and I would be honored if anyone can help me with this issue in a great details! Thanks in advance!
Well! I have a large text file that is made of group of 209 rows! In another words in my large file there is simple element with the following format that repeats many times (let us name it NR) . each element has 209 rows and 5 columns. I am interested in having the data corresponding to the last three columns for 6 specific rows in each element. these 6 rows ( let me call them r1 to r6) are constant for all of the NR loops.
The third column which is the first column of interest starts at character number 25 of the row i.e. cell number 25 and ends at character number 37. 
The forth column which is the second column of interest starts at character number 51 of the row i.e. cell number 51 and ends at 63.
The fifth column which is the third column of interest starts at character number 77 of the row i.e. cell number 77 and ends at 89.
 I need to create NR separated text files and have the data of interest be written in the following format for each of the NR loop:
1) For each file the first 16 lines (rows) there is a similar text that is required to be at each file. For example : 
"Thank you for your help!
I do appreciate it
and so on "
2) from Line 17 to Line 22 I need to print the data that has been read previously for r1 to r6 respectively,  such a way that information of third column is being printed at character (cell) number 24, information of forth column is being printed at character (cell) number 40 and information of fifth column is being printed at character (cell) number 56.
3) for lines 17-22 I need to add four new columns at cells number , 4,8,12 and 16 respectively such that 
A) the first column is 1 for r1, 2 for r2 and etc.
B) The second column is 1 for r1 and r2 and 2 for the r3 to r6
C) the third column is the same as second column
D) the forth column is always 0.
Wow! I know it might be so hard to get the point with the text :D
I hope you could help me with that !
So just to sum Up the points. I need NR separated files which names are from 1 to NR. Each of these NR files are related to the same loop in my large file.
Thanks!
All the best!

Comment: Your question is very complex and difficult to understand unless you provide at least an execerpt of the input file and, possibly an example of the desired output. Considering that you have to deal with text files containing string or chars, my suggestion is to not to use MatLab. Consider using, for example, AWK, Perl, Python.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I can provide you with an example of the input and desired output files! but I do not know how! :) Since I have no email address from u!

Comment: It is better to share the information (in this case the file) with all users. You can edit the question you made and add (copy & paste) some text from input file and example of the output. Please, make sure to use the formatting options in order to make it more readable.